# Conditional Formatting with a formula at Excel doesn't work

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I want to color the line by target date.

I made table like this
[image]

and set formatting rule as
[image]
if date is "2023/02/21", the background at that line should be changed to "pink"...

However, it doesn't work.

could you help me?

My expectation is changing background color like this[image]

Comment: Which cell is C4 and to what range did you apply your rule?

Comment: try : `=$C4="21/2/2023"*1`

Comment: Thanks so much! it's correct.
I don't know [*1]. it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does work, since "21/2/2023" represents a text and not a number, you need to use something as follows

[image]

```
=$C4="21/2/2023"*1
```

to get the row highlighted where the target dates is 21/2/2023, make it absolute relative reference as $C4 in your example .

Refer the applies to in screen-prints

[image]